# Gate operations for controlling Cat States

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, schroedingers-cat

Suppose I have a Cat state $|C_{\alpha}^{+}\rangle = | + \alpha\rangle + | - \alpha\rangle $. Is there a set of bosonic gate operations i.e. rotation, displacement, SNAP gate etc. (in phase space) that can map it to $|C_{\alpha}^{-}\rangle = |+ \alpha\rangle - |- \alpha\rangle$?

Comment: What is a SNAP gate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this approximately is with the displacement operator:

$$
D(i\beta) = \mathrm{exp}[i\beta(\hat{a}+\hat{a}^{\dagger})]
$$

where $\beta$ is assumed to be real. Applying this operator on the even cat state with $\alpha$ real as well we find:

$$
D(i\beta) (|\alpha\rangle + |-\alpha\rangle) = 
e^{i\alpha\beta}|\alpha+i\beta\rangle + e^{-i\alpha\beta}|-\alpha+i\beta\rangle
$$

Assuming that $\alpha$ is large we can choose $\alpha\beta = \pi/2$ while ensuring that $\alpha >> \beta$. Hence:

$$
D(i\beta) (|\alpha\rangle + |-\alpha\rangle) \approx i(|\alpha\rangle - |-\alpha\rangle)
$$

Essentially, we're doing a tiny displacement of the cat state in a direction orthogonal to the axis defined by the state, and this induces the correct conditional phase shift.

See also: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9809037.pdf

Comment: Thank you for answering! Can you please explain why do factors of $e^{i \alpha \beta}$ appear in front of the displaced states in the second line?

Comment: It's a basic property of the displacement operator, you can find proofs of it in many places, for example p.16 here: https://homepage.univie.ac.at/reinhold.bertlmann/pdfs/T2_Skript_Ch_5.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now:)